# How to get email notification of comments?

Tags: support, notifications

I would like to be notified by email when someone comments on my question or answer, or when there is a later comment on same item I've commented on.

E.g., let's say I ask a question, then someone comments on it, then I answer that comment with my own comment. If there is another comment after that, I would really like to know about it via email. I know that the notification mechanism exists in some form, because when I log back into the website, I see a red bar at the top notifying me of the new comments; I just can't figure out how to get notified by email.

An RSS feed would also work, but would be less ideal.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get notification of comments other than by checking on the site.

You can get notification of new answers by checking the option at the bottom of your question, but the preferred approach is to keep coming back to the site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris. I thought I had posted this question to http://meta.stackexchange.com, but I see that I actually posted it to http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com. Is there a really a difference in the "metadata" about how to use a Stack Exchange site? Maybe I should post a new question about this... (edit: or read the FAQ? :-)

Comment: @Steve - if it's a general question about any/all of the SE sites then most to http://meta.stackoverflow.com. meta.stackexchange is for the SE 1.0 sites which are winding down.

Answer (score 1):

While commenting there is an option to select notification to email for new comments just below the comment boxes in most of the blogs. This is the way to know about new comments.

If you want to get entire comments coming newly into the blog, you can also subscribe to the comment feed which usually present somewhere around the blog page footer.